# boost serialization with recursive shared pointer fails

Tags: c++, recursion, shared-ptr, boost-serialization

I have created a sample code that shows a class B derived from class A and A gets a shared pointer for B in the ctor.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

// #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
// #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/tmpdir.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

// forward declarations
class A;
class B;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class A {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) {
        // ar & text_a;
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(text_a);
        // ar & counter;
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(counter);
        // ar & pointer_class;
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(pointer_class);
    }
public:
    std::string    text_a{"default"};
    int            counter{0};
    boost::shared_ptr<B> pointer_class;
    // B            *pointer_class;
    A() {}
    A(boost::shared_ptr<B> pointer_class): pointer_class(pointer_class) {}
    // A(B *pointer_class): pointer_class(pointer_class) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SHARED_PTR(A)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class B: public A {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) {
        // first base classes
        // ar & boost::serialization::base_object<A>(*this);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(A);
        // then member fields
        // ar & text_b;
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(text_b);
    }
public:
    std::string    text_b{"default"};
    B(): A(boost::shared_ptr<B>(this)) {}
    // B(): A(this) {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SHARED_PTR(B)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

boost::shared_ptr<B> dataset;

void SaveDataset(std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str());
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive archive(ofs);
    if (!ofs.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "-- can't open file '" << filename << '\'' << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // oa << dataset;
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(dataset);
}

void LoadDataset(std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive archive(ifs);
    if (!ifs.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "-- can't open file '" << filename << '\'' << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // ia >> dataset;
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(dataset);
}

void PrintDataset() {
    std::cout << "text_a = '" << dataset->text_a << '\'' << std::endl;
    std::cout << "text_b = '" << dataset->text_b << '\'' << std::endl;
    std::cout << "counter = '" << dataset->counter << '\'' << std::endl;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string filename = "dataset.dat";
    // dataset = std::make_shared<B>();
    dataset = boost::shared_ptr<B>(new B());

    {
        // if file doesn't exit
        if (!boost::filesystem::exists(filename)) {
            // make some changes
            dataset->text_a = "hello";
            dataset->text_b = "world";

            // save dataset
            SaveDataset(filename);
            std::clog << "-- saved dataset" << std::endl;
        }

        // load dataset
        LoadDataset(filename);
        std::clog << "-- loaded dataset" << std::endl;

        // increment the counter twice
        dataset->counter++;
        dataset->pointer_class->counter++;

        // print dataset
        PrintDataset();

        // save dataset before exit for next time
        SaveDataset(filename);
        std::clog << "-- saved dataset" << std::endl;
    }

    // std::remove(filename.c_str());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Its possible to compile it, but at runtime I get:

```
prog.exe: /opt/wandbox/boost-1.66.0/gcc-head/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:698: void boost::shared_ptr<T>::reset(Y*) [with Y = B; T = B]: Assertion `p == 0 || p != px' failed.
```

Here is a [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P1oWQ9bY4uXDo1lM) for that sample code.

But it runs fine, if I change these three lines to c pointers:

```
boost::shared_ptr<B> pointer_class;
// B            *pointer_class;
A(boost::shared_ptr<B> pointer_class): pointer_class(pointer_class) {}
// A(B *pointer_class): pointer_class(pointer_class) {}
B(): A(boost::shared_ptr<B>(this)) {}
// B(): A(this) {}
```

Here is a working [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t0Zdl9mjvrpOT4mN) that is like the sample code above but with these three lines changes.

I tried also to use a third class C and put a shared pointer in class A. And the serial/deserial worked. But if there is recursion with a shared pointer like in this sample, it does not work. Any idea why?